# C#: парсинг XML в список Обьектов

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

Ошибка источника:

Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.

Сведения об исключении: System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

```
 Строка 192:            using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(stream))
 Строка 193:            {
 Строка 194:                adsList = (List<Ad>)serializer.Deserialize(sr2);
 Строка 195:                sr2.Close();
 Строка 196:            }
```

Полный листинг:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Ad
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // это поле встречается не во всех нодах xml файла
    [XmlElement("Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}




 public static void AdGet(string FileUrl, string filesrc)
    {
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "Ads";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Ad>),xRoot);
        String strResult;
        WebResponse objResponse;
        var adsList = new List<Ad>();
        WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(FileUrl);
        objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
            strResult = strResult.Replace(" formatVersion=\"3\"", "");
            sr.Close();
        }
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(strResult);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            adsList = (List<Ad>)serializer.Deserialize(sr2);
            sr2.Close();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Приведите более полный листинг. И какая ошибка?

Comment: Ясно, что определение класса не совпадает со схемой xml. Покажите xml, который пытаетесь десериализовать. Тогда можно будет дать совет, что исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Сериалайзеру нужно указать c каким типом объекта ему нужно работать

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
```

если не помогло, то значить у вас класс неправильный: несоответствие по свойствам, нет атрибута `[Serializable]`, у класса нет стандартного конструктора без параметров.

Comment: Атрибут `[Serializable]` классу `XmlSerializer` безразличен.